# How to make y axis only integer scaling in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, chart.js

I just a newbie to ChartJS,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCzzL.png)

I have 3 questions:

1.How can I make the Y axis only integer? where should I add it?

2.How can I turn off the title which is ""my open case"? I tried it to set it to null but dodn't work?

3.How can I turn off the background grids off? it looks weird

This is my code:

```
 var columnChart = document.getElementById("columnChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(columnChart, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {

                labels: columnChartLabel,
                datasets: [ {
                    label: 'My Open Case',
                    data: columnChartNumber,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)"
                }]
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 3):

> **How can I make the Y axis only integer? where should I add it?**

You can make the Y axis only integer by setting `stepSize` property to `1` for *ticks* in the chart options.

```
options: {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            stepSize: 1
         }
      }]
   }
}
```

see [tick configuration options](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#tick-configuration)

> **How can I turn off the title which is "my open case"?**

You can turn off the title *(aka Legend)* by setting `display` property to `false` for the *legend*.

```
options: {
   legend: {
      display: false
   }
}
```

see [legend configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration)

> **How can I turn off the background grids off?**

You can turn off the background grids by setting *gridLines*'s `display` property to `false` for both the x and y axis.

```
options: {
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{
         gridLines: {
            display: false
         }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
         gridLines: {
            display: false
         }
      }]
   }
}
```

see [grid line configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#grid-line-configuration)

**[ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ᴏɴ ᴊꜱꜰɪᴅᴅʟᴇ](https://jsfiddle.net/xt2zk7oh/)**

Comment: @slowjams [Did this answer help solving your problem? IF so then, be sure to accept it by clicking on the check mark beside(left) the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: This is the perfect answer what I want. Thanks!!

Comment: @GRUNT Could you give more help for me? I wanna fill vertical graph inside, and erase line outside of graph line.